Is it possible to add a tag to an already published npm package version?
I was working on an npm package, and I want to test that it's behaving correctly, so I published a version with
npm version preminor 
npm publish 

npm version preminor bumps the minor version and attaches a suffix like 1.1.0-0. I thought this would be enough for NPM treat this as an a non-latest release - but it turns out npm will default any publish without specified tags with the "latest" tag.
So now I have the scenario where I have a published 1.1.0-0 version and that's what people will get if they do a fresh install. Is possible to attach an unstable tag after the fact?
